# Angular js $setViewValue and $setTouched ==null error

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

I am new to angular js and i am facing a problem in using md-datepicker in my code.

Currently the issue is when I am trying to validate the date, it is showing red color when though the date is rightly entered. As second issue is that it does not picking up the date and giving $setviewvalue null error.

I am using md-datepicker in two different forms first problem is from form 1 and the second one is from form 2

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: As @NituBansal said you need to post some code so we were able to help you